# How to create a snack bar that appears in all screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, snackbar

I need to create a snack bar that appears when there is no connectivity,
I had created one but it appears only in one screen, how can i make it visible in all screens whenever there is no connectivity.

In my home screen I call this `checkInternet(context);`  in the init method. It works perfectly in the home screen but when i navigate to other screens it doesn't show the snackbar.

My check internet function:

```
import 'package:flushbar/flushbar.dart';

checkInternet(BuildContext context) async {

  // actively listen for status updates
  var listener = DataConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((status) {
print('networrk status $status');
    switch (status) {
      case DataConnectionStatus.connected:
        shownewFlushBar(context,Colors.green,'You are Online',false);
        break;
      case DataConnectionStatus.disconnected:
        shownewFlushBar(context,Colors.red,'You are Offline',true);
        break;
    }
  });

  return await DataConnectionChecker().connectionStatus;
}

void shownewFlushBar(BuildContext context,Color bgcolor,String text,bool pindic)
{
  Flushbar(
    showProgressIndicator: pindic,
    message: text,
    backgroundColor: bgcolor,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    isDismissible: false,
  )..show(context);
}
```

Can anyone help me wwith this.

Comment: I used pub.dev/packages/flashbar for that. I find snackbar hard to use because of the reason you mentioned

Comment: Your problem is you have many Scaffolds and Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar); is tricky to use right?

Comment: I use the flushbar package. My issue is it shows the snackbar in the home screen whenever the connectivity changes, but when i navigate to other screen and then the connectivity change it doesn't appear.

Comment: I will update my question

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you recirect to another screen just check internet connectivity in your `build` method

Dependecy : `connectivity: 0.4.3+6`

**1)  First option**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

       var isConnected = await isInternetConnected();
       if (isConnected != true) {
          // Snackbar show here
       }
  }
```

Check internet connetion using this method

```
  Future<bool> isInternetConnected() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
        connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

**2)  Second option**

Add listener in `initState()` of  `main.dart` file so whenever connection is change you get response

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result){
      if(result == ConnectivityResult.none){

          // use Future.delayed() if you want context in initState
          Future.delayed(Duration.zero,(){
            print(" Internet connection is lost");        
          });

      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: having ` var isConnected = await isInternetConnected();
       if (isConnected != true) {
          // Snackbar show here
       }` in your build method is not neat and will cause unnecessary computation during widget rebuild. Having it under `initState()` is better but how did you `await` a non-async function under `build()`. I don't know if `Connecivity`  plugin promise to close that stream you're listening to under the `iniState`.  It'll help the community a lot if you could refactor the code.